# How to output an alert message when embedded link does not exist?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, forms, hyperlink

I have this piece of code and I was wondering how I would be able to display an alert message when the embedded link does not exist. Is this possible?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function soniaZsound(track) {
    var link = 'https://ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/de/0/'+track+'.mp3';

    document.getElementById("myspan").innerHTML='<embed src="'+link+'"' +
      'onError="alert("sorry this word is not in the database");"' + 
      '`autostart=true loop=false hidden=true` type="audio/mp3">';
    }
</script> 

<body>    
  <span id="myspan"></span>
  <form name= "searchwords" id="searchwords"> 
    How does this word sound: <input type="text" name= "soundSearch"><input type="button"
    value="GO" onclick="soniaZsound(document.forms['searchwords']['soundSearch'].value);">
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: if you got that error is because the file "loveu.mp3" does not exist. Btw, I think that domain doesn't allow content being opened from another domain... (I understood your question wrong, as if you wanted to check the src of the embed tag. So I removed my answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are allowed to read content from that domain you can do a HTTP HEAD request to see if the file exists:

```
$.ajax({
url:'http://www.example.com/somefile.ext',
type:'HEAD',
error:
    function(){
        //file does not exists
    },
success:
    function(){
        //file exists
    }
```

});